# Mark headings or items as TODO in Google documents

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Is it possible to somehow mark/flag/tag a heading in a Google document as a TODO?

Furthermore, is it possible to aggregate the tagged todos from all the documents on the Google Drive?

Answer (score 2):

No there is no such feature available at the moment.